# Twitter Feed SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, twitter

I have created a twitter feed to appear on sharepoint 2013 page. this works fine when twitter isn't blocked for the school.

is there a way of copying the tweets into sharepoint to display at ALL times even if twitter is blocked by the firewall?

SharePoint site is hosted at a site where twitter isn't blocked.